# MUI Autocomplete onChange won't updates value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm fetching autocomplete options from API, it fetches perfectly, and it shows the options already selected back from API, but the error I'm facing is that whenever I try to delete or remove a value (category) it won't remove or add.

For online Demo [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-williamson-inn731?file=/src/components/autocomplete/SelectPostsCatsOptions.jsx)

**PostInfo.jsx:**

```
import SelectPostsCatsOptions from "../../components/autocomplete/SelectPostsCatsOptions";
import postInfo from "./postInfo.json";
export default function PostInfo() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPost = async () => {
      try {
        setCategories(postInfo[0].categories);
        setSelectedCategories(postInfo[0].categories);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getPost();
  });

  return (
   
    <div className="PostInfoPage">
      <>
        <div>
          <form>
            <div>
              <h3>Post Categories:</h3>
              <SelectPostsCatsOptions
                selectedCategories={selectedCategories}
                setSelectedCategories={setSelectedCategories}
                onChange={(event, newSelectedCategories) =>
                  setSelectedCategories(newSelectedCategories)
                }
                value={selectedCategories}
              />
              <p>Selected Categories:</p>
            </div>
          </form> 
        </div>
      </>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SelectPostsCatsOptions:**

```
import categories from "./postsCategories.json";

export default function SelectPostsCatsOptions({
  selectedCategories,
  setSelectedCategories,
  onChange,
  value
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        id="categories"
        disablePortal
        multiple
        getOptionLabel={(category) => category.catName}
        options={categories}
        disableGutters
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
          option.catName === value.catName
        }
        renderOption={(props, categories) => (
          <li {...props} key={categories.id}>
            {categories.catName}
          </li>
        )}
        renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip
              key={option.id}
              label={option.catName}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
          ))
        }
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} placeholder="Categories" />
        )}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know what i'm missing here, why i can't add or remove one tag from the autocomplete!

Answer (score 0):

Update you `useEffect` deps array.
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
`[]` mean just call on mount

it's getting called every render

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPost = async () => {
      try {
        setCategories(postInfo[0].categories);
        setSelectedCategories(postInfo[0].categories);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getPost();
  }, []); //<--- change
```

Comment: Now I get this warning: MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `["jkflnbr.efb","kj.sfbalkdfb","sfnojblkigpsm"]`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.

Comment: Not happening for me in this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-williamson-inn731?file=/src/pages/PostInfo/PostInfo.jsx:817-835

Can you help me with repro?